# Stream on the fly zipped files to client via rest endpoint

Tags: .net-core, zip, c#-ziparchive

I am trying to stream on the fly zipped files but memory consumption is high. For example, to zip total file size of 2.8 GB is taking nearly 5 GB  of processor memory.

```cs
    [Route("zip")]    
    public class ZipController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        public ZipController()
        {
            _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task Zip([FromBody] JsonToZipInput input)
        {        

            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.Headers.Add($"Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename=\"{input.FileName}\"");
        
            using var zipArchive =
                new ZipArchive(Response.BodyWriter.AsStream(), ZipArchiveMode.Create);
            foreach (var (key, value) in input.FilePathsToUrls)
            {
                var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(key, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                await using var zipStream = zipEntry.Open();
                await using var stream = await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync(value);
                await stream.CopyToAsync(zipStream);
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should be able to call `Response.StartAsync`:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task Zip([FromBody] JsonToZipInput input)
{        
  Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
  Response.Headers.Add($"Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename=\"{input.FileName}\"");

  await Response.StartAsync();
    
  using var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(Response.BodyWriter.AsStream(), ZipArchiveMode.Create);
  foreach (var (key, value) in input.FilePathsToUrls)
  {
    var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(key, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
    await using var zipStream = zipEntry.Open();
    await using var stream = await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync(value);
    await stream.CopyToAsync(zipStream);
  }
}
```

`StartAsync` should start the response being sent. Note that neither the *response headers* nor the *status code* can be modified once `StartAsync` is called.

In particular, this means that your exception handling will be different. Previously, an exception (e.g., from a bad URL in the request) would cause an exceptional status code (i.e., 500). With a streaming response, any exceptions after `StartAsync` cannot change the status code; it's already been sent. Instead, it will appear to the client as though the connection was terminated without a clean close. Complicating this a bit further, this behavior is not uncommon for web servers to do in the *successful* case, so clients may not complain - they would just end up with truncated (invalid) zip files. (In the case of streaming zips, the "file table" in the zip is sent last instead of first).

So, this should work, but I also recommend:

1. Ensure your exception logging works for exceptions after `StartAsync`. There is no way to return error details to the client, so you must rely on logging.
2. If you control the client, test out this new error situation, and see if you can detect it. If it's not detectable using that client, then ensure your code validates the zip.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing about the zip file format should require a large amount of memory for this use case.  It's essential all the files in order, with a table at the end describing the zip structure, and file offsets. This makes it possible to stream very efficiently without using much memory at all.

You may not need to write this yourself, [ZipStreamer](https://github.com/scosman/zipstreamer) is a micro service you host that does exactly this (disclosure, I'm the author). It's designed to solve the exact problems you are hitting by streaming the bytes out as soon as they come in, with a fixed buffer size to prevent blowing up memory. It can stream hundreds of zips files in parallel using only a few MB of memory.

If you need this to be part of your application, here are some suggestions.

- Disable compression will save CPU, and a bit of memory. Depending on your files, compression might not be a major benefit (jpegs actually get bigger after zip compression). If you're zipping just to combine many files into one, this will really help. But this doesn't explain using GB of memory.
- Ensure you're not holding the stream content any longer than you need to, it looks like you are. Start streaming back asap as @Stephen suggested with StartAsync.